# How to send/Receive data in ServiceBus message header

Tags: azure, azure-functions, servicebus

I'm using Azure functions to send and receive messages from service bus. I want to send and receive correlationId in service bus message header to track message lifecycle.

I'm sending first JSON payload from ServiceBusExplore, and getting text If using string insted of BrokeredMessage

**Receiver Code**

```
public static async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("validate-trade", AccessRights.Manage,
        Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]BrokeredMessage message,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        string queueData = message.GetBody<string>();
}
```

getting below error

```
'message.GetBody<string>()' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException'    string {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException}
```

I tried this as well

```
string s = receiveMessage.GetBody<string>(new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the safest way to read contents of any Service Bus message as pure string:

```cs
string body;
using (var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>())
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    body = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```